# Java Program to add two strings values

Tags: java, string

There are Two Strings s1 and s2, then split them and add them with one another.

Please find below snippet for more information,

**Input :-**

String s1 ="Sheldon Cooper";

String s2 ="Howard Wolowitz";

**Output :-**

Sheldon Wolowitz

Howard Cooper

Can anyone help me on this....

Comment: `find below snippet` ... you forgot the snippet - input and output aren't "a snippet"

Comment: Hint: Make sure of the [`String.split(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Split String method in java

```
String[] arrOfS1 = s1.split(" ");
String[] arrOfS2 = s2.split(" ");
System.out.println(arrOfS1[0] + " " + arrOfS2[1]);
System.out.println(arrOfS2[0] + " " + arrOfS1[1]);
```